# Postgres JSON Aggregation for more than 3 many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE first 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE second 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE third 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE first_second 
(
    first_id INTEGER REFERENCES first(id),
    second_id INTEGER REFERENCES second(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (first_id, second_id)
);

CREATE TABLE second_third 
(
    second_id INTEGER REFERENCES second(id),
    third_id INTEGER REFERENCES third(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (second_id, third_id)
);
```

I need a query to retrieve json result with this format:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "seconds": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "thirds": [
          {
            "id": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have this query for just two tables. I could not write for three tables:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_AGG(firsts) AS firsts 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         f."id", 
         JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('id', s."id")) AS seconds 
     FROM 
         "first" f 
     INNER JOIN 
         "first_second" fs ON fs."first_id" = f."id"
     INNER JOIN 
         "second" s ON s."id" = fs."second_id" 
     GROUP BY 
         f."id") AS firsts
```

Comment: So what have you tried and what issue are you facing?

Comment: Can you add the DDL relative to the insert statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query, where I aggregated data from three interrelated tables `(`first`,` second`,` third`)` using nested JSON aggregation in `PostgreSQL` to construct a hierarchical JSON structure, where each "`first`" entity contains an array of "`seconds`", each of which in turn contains an array of "`thirds`".

```
SELECT 
    JSON_AGG(
        JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
            'id', f.id, 
            'seconds', seconds
        )
    ) AS result
FROM 
    first f
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        fs.first_id, 
        JSON_AGG(
            JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                'id', s.id, 
                'thirds', thirds
            )
        ) AS seconds
    FROM 
        first_second fs
    INNER JOIN 
        second s ON fs.second_id = s.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            st.second_id, 
            JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('id', t.id)) AS thirds
        FROM 
            second_third st
        INNER JOIN 
            third t ON st.third_id = t.id
        GROUP BY 
            st.second_id
    ) AS st ON s.id = st.second_id
    GROUP BY 
        fs.first_id
) AS fs ON f.id = fs.first_id
GROUP BY 
    f.id;
```